Proving a sequence fluctuating around its limit point converges.
(I don’t know whether there is a name for this kind of sequences so I just described its pattern in my words. Please edit it or tell me if there is a better title.)
The sequence defined by $x_n=\frac{a}{1+x_{n-1}}$ $(x_0,a>0)$ obviously converges to $\frac{\sqrt{4a+1}-1}{2}$, for its terms being greater than or smaller than that value alternatively but getting closer to it.
I am wondering how can I prove this observation. It seems that the typical way of doing it with monotone convergence theorem can’t work. I have tried to apply the monotone convergence theorem to an auxiliary sequence $y_n=|x_n-\frac{\sqrt{4a+1}-1}{2}|$ or $y_n=(x_n-\frac{\sqrt{4a+1}-1}{2})^2$ . For the first choice, I have no idea how can I show it is decreasing due to the troublesome absolute value. For the second choice, it seemed more workable to me but still I can’t figure how to obtain the inequality I want.
I think induction won’t work as showing the base case is essentially the same as doing the induction step in this question.

After posing this question, I realised a way proving it with the ε-N definition. First we can show the sub-sequences of it consisting of its odd terms and even terms respectively converges to $l=\frac{\sqrt{4a+1}-1}{2}$. Then we can use the definition, showing that $|x_n-l|<ε$ for sufficient large n, regardless of the parity of it. However this approach sounds cumbersome to me.

Let $r:={1\over 2}[\sqrt{4a+1}-1]$ and $s:={1\over 2}[-\sqrt{4a+1}-1].$ The numbers $r>0,\ s<0$ are the roots of the function $x^2+x-a.$ Moreover as $r^2+r-a=0$ there holds $r<a.$
Observe that
$$x_n-r=-{r\over 1+x_{n-1}}(x_{n-1}-r)\quad (*)$$
Assume $x_0>r.$ By $(*)$ we get $(-1)^n(x_n-r)>0,$ hence  $x_{2n}>r$ for any $n.$ We will show that $x_{2n}$ is decreasing. Indeed
$$x_{2n+2}={a\over 1+x_{2n+1}}={a\over 1+{a\over 1+x_{2n}}}={a(1+x_{2n})\over 1+x_{2n}+a}\quad (**)$$ Thus
$$x_{2n}-x_{2n+2}= {x_{2n}^2+x_{2n}-a\over 1+x_{2n}+a}={(x_{2n}-r)(x_{2n}-s)\over 1+x_{2n}+a}>0\quad (***)$$
The monotonicity implies that $x_{2n}$ is convergent. Hence the RHS in $(***)$ tends to $0.$ This is possible iff $x_{2n}$ tends to $r.$ By the recurrence relation $x_{2n-1}$ tends to $r$ as well.
For $x_0<r$ we get $x_1>r.$ Then the reasoning above shows that the sequence $x_{2n-1}$ is decreasing and convergent to $r.$ Hence $x_{2n}\to r.$
Remark It is possible to determine the rate of convergence. At the same time we get an alternative way of proving the convergence. For $x_0>r$ we have
$$ x_{2n+2}-r={a-r\over 1+a+x_{2n}}(x_{2n}-r)\le {a-r\over 1+a+r}(x_{2n}-r)$$
By iteration we get
$$0<x_{2n}-r\le  \left ({a-r\over 1+a+r}\right )^n(x_0-r)$$ Next $(*)$ for implies
$$0<r-x_{2n+1}\le r(x_{2n}-r)\le r\left ({a-r\over 1+a+r}\right )^n(x_0-r) $$ The coefficient $(a-r)/(1+a+r)$ is less than $1$, thus the convergence is exponential. For $x_0<r$ we get in the similar way
$$ 0<x_{2n+1}-r\le  \left ({a-r\over 1+a+r}\right )^n(x_1-r)$$
$$ 0<r-x_{2n+2}\le r(x_{2n+1}-r)\le  r\left ({a-r\over 1+a+r}\right )^n(x_1-r)$$

You should check out the fixed point theorem. Alternating convergence for a sequence $x_{n+1}=g(x_n)$ appears when $-1 < g' < 0$ (in some neighborhood of the fixed point). In your case, $g'<0$ and the convergence must be alternate. You can also just use Lagrange's theorem: If $z$ is the fixed point, in your case $z = \frac{\sqrt{4a+1}-1}{2}$, we have that
$$
(x_{n+1}-z)(x_{n}-z)=(g(x_n)-g(z))(x_n-z) = g'(\xi_n)(x_n-z)^2 < 0.
$$
